# vuejs: Props и v-if не дружат, почему такое поведение?

Tags: vue.js, axios

Небольшая программа на вью - старая, тогда основы изучал и так и осталась реализация без vue-cli.
Есть файлик js и html. В html содержится контейнер приложения и шаблон **модульного окна**.
В js содержится все: есть корневой компонент, в него входят другие, но интересует именно модульное окно - это один уровень вложенности.
Итак: корневой компонент на created получает с сервера настройки для отображения формы (ajax(axios)), которая располагается в модульном окне. Он получает список процедур для вывода `v-for` и получает настройки для отображения полей ввода. В виде:

```
formSettings:{
name: {used:true, required:true},
phone: {used:false, required:false},
.....
}
```

В компонент модульного окна настройки и список "пробрасываются" в `props` - `procedureList` и `siteSettings`, т.е.:

```
Vue.component('#myModalForm' ,{
props: ['procedureList', 'siteSettings'],
data: function(){return}
}
```

Далее в `#myModalForm` есть разметка, примерно так:

```
<div v-for="procedure in procedureList">
<div>{{ procedure.name }}</div>
</div>
```

И в ней проблем нет - все корректно отображается. А проблемы есть, ниже:

```
<div v-if="siteSettings.name.used"></div>
```

Тут полное игнорирование, всегда "правда".
Т.е. компонент "не видит" пробрасываемые данные. Если на форму поставить кнопку и по щелчку изменить свойство, то `v-if` срабатывает. Выводил в консоль - `siteSettings.name.used == false`, как только прилетают `created` по созданию корневого компонента. Единственная странность, chrome после прилета данных выводит в консоль `false` черным цветом, а после изменения с помощью событий(по щелчку) - синим.
В чем может быть проблема?
Я еще добавлю, что в корневом элементе создавал в `data` аналог присылаемого с сервера объекта и настройки этого объекта применяются к модальному окну, но применяются такими какими заложены в коде, после того как прилетают новые данные с сервера - ничего не менятеся в работе `v-if` модалки. А в консоли все нормально.

Answer (score 0):

Ларчик просто открывался, подсказали на тостере: черным приходила строка с сервера, которая само собой приводилась к bool(true) и v-if всегда отображал данные.